# Trigger a function when action is dispatched from other component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am working on a reactjs application and using redux. I am having two components. Say **Component A** and **Component B**. In component A I have a table. When I click any row, I dispatcch an action with row's data as parameters of that action. Every time I click a row, this action is dispatched. I want to trigger a function in Component B whenever a row is clicked and that action is dispatched. How can I do it?

Normally we change the data in reducer via action dispatch and then use that data as state in other components. But here i want to trigger a function in Component B whenever a row is clicked in the table of component A.

Comment: Is component B parent of component A?

Comment: No. They are seperate.

Answer (score 1):

Dispatch an action in A when row clicked, that sets a boolean value to true. Then use `mapStateToProps` to re-render the component on Redux state change. Then make a conditional call to the required function inside `componentDidUpdate()`:

```
class B extends React.Component {
  componentDidUpdate() {
    const { rowClickedInAComponent } = this.props;
    if ( rowClickedInAComponent ) {
      functionToBeCalled();
    }
  }
  render() {
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  rowClickedInAComponent: rowClickedInAComponent
  // boolean here, you could pass any info such as which row was clicked
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ListingPage);
```

Comment if you need further clarification.

Comment: yes it is. But you can pass any value, as I mentioned in the comment

Comment: So functionToBeCalled() will be executed everytime even when flag value changes from "true" to "true". I mean everytime I click the row, functionToBeCalled() will be executed?

Comment: no, for that you have to pass any other value that is sure to change each time. I'm sure you would want to pass some info about which row was clicked.

Comment: See that  is the problem. If something changes in the reducer then how should I do a check on it? Say the row id changes. Now what to do with that?

Comment: Also I my component B is video player. So when I play the player, componentUpdate runs infinitely. Any solution for this?

Comment: send the rowID along with the `dispatch` and use it to compare between previous `props` and current `props` inside `componentDidUpdate`. See https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/update/postrender_with_componentdidupdate.html for example. **`componentDidUpdate` runs infinitely as long as your component updates, even if you don't add any logic there. That's React's behavior**. But I don't understand why your component updates when the video is being played. Try putting a `console.log` inside your `render`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156982/discussion-between-apurvg-and-dane).

Comment: where I am, I can't :) sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this through couple of ways some are the following.

i) If there is **parent child** relation just pass `activeRow` function as a `props` of child component

```js
  class ComponentA extends React.component{

  render(){
    return(
    {/*view, could be table, section, div, etc.*/}
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.props.handler}>Click me</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class ComponentB extends React.component{

  handleClick(){
    //do something.
    console.log("clicked!");
  }
  
  render(){
    return(
    {/*view, could be table, section, div, etc.*/}
      <div>
        <ComponentA handler={this.handleClick}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

ii)Using redux, create an `activeRow` key in redux state and `subscribe` componentB using **react-redux's** `connect` method. 
Now in `componentB` add `componentWillReceiveProps` life cycle hook, and do something in inside `componentWillReceiveProps` 
Ex:

```js
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
  //first parameter is updated props.
  //check this.props with nextProps.
  //do something here.
}
```

Comment: But this.state.activeRow.id and props.activeRow.id both are same. Right? You must be going this.state.activeRow.id = props.activeRow.id to maintain the  this.state.activeRow.id. So at any point of time, how will they be not equal?

Comment: Then we don't get your logic :( Why would you want to update if the row ID hasnt changed ?

Comment: Row id is changing. But as soon as row id changes  this.state.activeRow.id will also get changed, right? As we must be doing setState({ this.state.activeRow.id:  props.activeRow.id })

Comment: How about  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
       
        if ( nextProps == this.props) {
            this.skipTime(this.props.sentance_selected_reducer.sentanceTime);

        }
    }

Comment: Looks good. But please do deep checking using `props` keys instead of just `nextProps === this.props`

Comment: Actually in state.activeRow.id is previous selected row and in props.activeRow.id is newly selected/updated props, both are different.

Comment: it is an example case, you can do what you want